# Rails POST getting handled by controller#home

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. I have a Projects resource:

```
resources :projects
```

In ProjectsController#new, I'm creating a project and rendering it in new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for @project do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :name %>
  <%= f.text_field :name%><br/>
  <%= f.submit  %>
<% end %>
```

This gets POSTed but instead of being handled by Projects#create it's being handled by the home action:

```
Started POST "/projects" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-02 08:47:36 -0500
Processing by ProjectsController#home as HTML
```

Here are my routes:

```
                    /                            projects#home
    projects        /projects(.:format)          projects#home
             GET    /projects(.:format)          projects#index
             POST   /projects(.:format)          projects#create
 new_project GET    /projects/new(.:format)      projects#new
edit_project GET    /projects/:id/edit(.:format) projects#edit
     project GET    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#show
             PUT    /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#update
             DELETE /projects/:id(.:format)      projects#destroy
```

EDITED:
I found the problem.

This is the old routes file:

```
SolarMesh::Application.routes.draw do
  match '/' => 'projects#home'
  match '/projects' => 'projects#home'
  resources :projects

end
```

The line "match '/projects'" was the reason it was always being handled by home.

Comment: can you please show your routes file

Comment: Perhaps you should post the new and create methods code from your projects controller

Comment: Also check the url for your index action...

Comment: I edited the question with the routes file. Thnaks for the comments.

Answer (score 0):

Show me your routes file.........
The problem is in the second and the third lines of your route file where you have not specfied the http verb in the second line and thus it would go to the home action instead of the create action...so please specify the verb in your routes file in order to prevent this error in the future...

Answer (score 0):

your route file should be this

```
SolarMesh::Application.routes.draw do
   resources :projects
   match '/projects' => 'projects#home'
   match '/' => 'projects#home'

end
```

and this will solve your problem

because when you were specifying those urls before the resource declaration they were restricting the index page to run now it should run

Comment: Isn't this line redundant? 

match '/' => 'projects#home'

Comment: resources :project provides the route to home as '/'

Comment: the point is that when you  were keeping  /projects above the defaul then it was causing route gobbling problem all the type of verbs( PUT, Get ,Delete, Post ) were handled by home and respective action such as create or index wouldn't have been called